# validation for radio button list in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

this page contains 2 itemlist for radio button,if i select itemlist  value "accept"then text box validation is not required, for another value "reject" validation is required (to fill the textbox)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
         OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
         <Columns>

         <asp:BoundField DataField="GradeID" HeaderText="GradeID"  SortExpression="GradeID" />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Diagnosis" HeaderText="Diagnosis" SortExpression="Diagnosis" />

                     <asp:BoundField DataField="MileStoneID" HeaderText="MileStoneID" SortExpression="MileStoneID" />

<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Feedback">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>


                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select one">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Rd1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" DataTextField='<%DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Feedback")%>'  EnableViewState="false"   >
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Accept" Value="1"  ></asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"  ></asp:ListItem>
                                                      </asp:RadioButtonList>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select one">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>


                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="submit">
                     <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandName="select"EnableViewState="false" 
        />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

in aspx.cs page

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "select") //for selecting Button
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Rd1");//for selecting the particular radio button list
            if (rbl.SelectedValue == "1") //for selecting the radiobuttonlist option for accepting the data
            {
//here it should ask for fill the textbox feedback
            }
            else

                if (rbl.SelectedValue == "2") //for rejecting the data
                {
                    //here validation is required to fill the textbox
                }

        }
    }

}

    protected void Rd1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     RadioButtonList Rd = (RadioButtonList)sender;
     Rd.Items[1].Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('have you fill the feedback?')"); //for giving confirmation box when we click reject button

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
          if (e.CommandName == "select") //for selecting Button
            {
              GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((RadioButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Rd1");
              //for selecting the particular radio button list
                if (rbl.SelectedValue == "1")  //for selecting the radiobuttonlist option for accepting the data
                {
                     //here it should ask for fill the textbox feedback
                }
                else if (rbl.SelectedValue == "2") //for rejecting the data
                {
                     //here validation is required to fill the textbox
                }
            }
}


 protected void Rd1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
     RadioButtonList Rd = (RadioButton) e.Row.FindControl("Rd1");
     Rd.Items[1].Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return confirm('have you fill the feedback?')"); //for giving confirmation box when we click reject button
       }
     }
```

Comment: I did not get the output...please help

Comment: please send what you want exactly

Comment: I want validation for selected list item "reject" that to fill the feedback,if i select list item as an "accept" then it should not ask to fill the textbox(feedback). That confirmation works ,but it is only for confirming if i confirm also it won't show what i want.Pleas help.